# What kind of tree has this blossom?

Tags: trees

I filmed this beautiful blossom on a tree, this past spring in Toronto, Ontario, Canada.

[image]

Comment: Is it a small tree? It's clearly in the rose family, but that includes apples, pears, quinces, apricots, plums, cherries, peaches, raspberries, blackberries, loquats, strawberries, roses (duh), hawthorns, almonds and more. Best guess? Some kind of plum, like (but not) Thundercloud Plum, because the leaves are out as well as the buds, and the leaves will be burgundy colored. It might also be a crabapple, likely Crabapple "Royalty", but the bark is off. It would help to have a better picture of the leaves and bark, Not an answer because I'm guessing.

Comment: Woah, just saw your other posts. You did this last year; you posted a bunch of photos you took in a botanical garden then asked for their names. It's one thing to be genuinely curious about a plant you've come across; it's another thing altogether to take a bunch of photos and ask someone else to identify them for you so that you can label them on your site (or whatever.) -1.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your guess and the intel anongoodnurse. It is a fairly large tree in my neighbourhood. Probably 25 feet high, 20 circumference. 

Re. your other comment, I shoot stock footage so i'm really particular about describing what i have shot accurately. I am also genuinely curious about this beautiful world of ours that we live in! I also don't think it hurts to increase knowledge on stack exchange via these pics? For example, I posted a pic of a beetle a while back, which prompted a really great and interesting discussion that many people benefitted from, including me!

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I think you're asking others to do work that you should have done yourself at the time you took the photos.